# how to display incomplete display the “DDL” of tengine’ table?

Tags: tdengine

I am using tdengine. I met a problem that when I check the DDL of a table.Using the command below:

```
Show create table question;
```

While my query result displayed by taos shell is incomplete. Just like this picture.[image: query result]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean complete the query result while displayed by taos shell. Due to the limited display width of taos shell in the terminal, it is possible that a relatively long column is not displayed completely.
The workaround can be by modifying the setting option "`maxBinaryDisplayWidth`" in the taos.cfg file, or directly entering the command set `max_binary_display_width 100`. Or, use the `\G` parameter at the end of the command to adjust how the results are displayed.